# I have class models in angular having variables and functions so when I call the function it gives me error

Tags: angular, angular-cli

in my angular cli application I want to list patients full name I created models for patient containing both variable and function and created array of that model when I call one of the functions I get error says:

> v.context.$implicit.getFullName is not a function
>       at Object.eval [as updateRenderer]

I tried to deserialize the class it did not work

```
export interface DeSerialize {
  deSerialize(input: any): this;
}
```

```
import { DeSerialize } from "../utils/DeSerialize";

export class Patient implements DeSerialize {
  patientId: number;
  firstName: string;
  midName?: string;
  lastName?: string;
  mobile?: string;
  gender: string;
  comment: string;
  address: string;
  dateOfBirth: Date;
  email: string;

deSerialize(input: any): this {
    Object.assign(this, input);
    return this;
  }

  public getFullName() {
    return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
  }
}
```

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

patients: Patient[];
constructor(private data: AppService) {
this.patients = [];
}

ngOnInit() {

    this.data.getPatients().subscribe(patients => {
      this.patients = patients;
      // console.log(patients[0].getFullName());
    });
  }
}
```

```
<ul *ngFor="let patient of patients">
    <li>{{ patient.getFullName() }}</li>
</ul>
```

I expect output should be like

```
John
Alan
James
```

Comment: what does `data.getPatients()` return? Does it indeed return an array of `Patient` objects or just typed as `Patient`? I suspect the latter.

Comment: it returns an array of patients

Answer (score 0):

You never created the Patient with 'new'. By the way,
`deSerialize()` will never run. Only if you call it directly on the object instance, therefore you need a constructor instead of `deSerialize()`.

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  patients: Patient[] = [];

  /* !data is not so descriptive..., AppService is too generic! */
  constructor(private data: AppService) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void /* !use types! */ {
    this.data.getPatients().subscribe(patients => {
      this.patients = patients.map(patient => new Patient(patient));
      console.log(this.patients[0].getFullName());
    });
  }
}

export class Patient {
  patientId: number;
  firstName: string;
  midName?: string;
  lastName?: string;
  mobile?: string;
  gender: string;
  comment: string;
  address: string;
  dateOfBirth: Date;
  email: string;

  constructor(patient: Patient) {
    Object.assign(this, patient);
  }

  getFullName(): string /* !use types, if public then don't write 'public'! */ {
    return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
  }
}
```

Comment: You are most likely right, but how do you know that OP has not create instances of class in `data.getPatients()`??

Comment: Note that it's not required to specify return types for methods.